# App Store charge for "Premier (Automatic Renewal)"

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore, itunes-store, in-app-purchase, apple-one

Today I received an emailed Apple / App Store receipt for a $29.95 charge.

> Your receipt from Apple.
>
> Premier (Automatic Renewal) $29.95
> Premier (Automatic Renewal) (Monthly)

I don't recognize this "Premier (Automatic Renewal)" charge.

Is it an in-app purchase? Why is the app name no listed? What service is this "Premier (Automatic Renewal)" for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Premier (Automatic Renewal)" is the name of the charge for the [Apple One](https://www.apple.com/apple-one/) plan containing 2TB of iCloud+ Backup:

[image]

Despite the mysterious email subject and IAP name, the full email make it clear that this is for "Apple Services":

[image: Apple Services - Apple One - Premier (Automatic Renewal)]

It also has an "Apple One" image, although this image was initially blocked in my email app. There is no other mention in the email of Apple One.